# Is a car with a licence plate that wasn't issued in Shanghai allowed to be driven within the Shanghai Outer Ring Expressway? Any restrictions if so?

Tags: legal, china, driving, shanghai

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vehicle_registration_plates_of_China&oldid=989322105#Shanghai:

> The initial character on licence plates issued in [Shanghai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai) is: [沪](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B2%AA) (*Hù*)
>
> - 沪A, 沪B, 沪D, 沪E, 沪F, 沪G, 沪H, 沪J, 沪K, 沪L, 沪M, 沪N — Urban area and suburbs.
> - 沪C — Suburbs, not allowed to enter the urban area (i.e. not allowed to travel within the Outer Ring).
> - 沪R — [Chongming Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chongming_Island), [Changxing Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changxing_Island_(Shanghai)), [Hengsha Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hengsha_Island), not allowed to leave the places above.

This makes me wonder:
Is a car with a license plate that wasn't [issued in Shanghai](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/225504857) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201228220058/https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/225504857)) allowed to be driven within the [Shanghai Outer Ring Expressway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_Outer_Ring_Expressway)? If so, is there any restriction?

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain why?

Comment: Per this news article from Oct 2020, cars with non-Shanghai plates are banned on many key roads during weekday business hours.  Weekends and at night are still OK. https://www.shine.cn/news/metro/2010248352/

Comment: Actual question: how did you get a drivers license for china? (if I remember correctly, international ones do not work)

Comment: @lalala https://www.travelchinacheaper.com/china-drivers-license-guide/amp

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica ->  [Be more proactive when a user continuously downvotes another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355329/178179).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-Shanghai permanent plates are, in general, not prohibited within S20. 沪C suburban ones  and temporary plates from other provinces are however prohibited.

As the [link](https://www.shine.cn/news/metro/2012061173/) provided by @lambshaanxy says, they are now not allowed on the specified elevated roads within the area circled by S20 during daytime (7h - 20h) on working days. S20 itself is not on the list. Using the surface roads is still allowed.

However, [more restrictions](https://www.thepaper.cn/newsDetail_forward_9697888) are coming after the 2021 [Labour Day Golden Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Week_%28China%29?wprov=sfla1). Non-Shanghai plates will not be allowed on surface roads within the [Inner Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_Ring_Road_(Shanghai)) during peak times (7h - 10h, 16h - 19h) on working days.